# How to use Zend_Search_Lucene as a separate component outside Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

As the optimization process of Zend_Search_Lucene index file using the optimize() method takes few seconds to complete, I want to create a Cron Job so that the optimization process of Index file will be done automatic everyday.

But I am not able to use the Zend_Search_Lucene component separately outside the Zend Framework.

I am using Zend Framework 1.

I have already created the Zend_Search_Lucene index file.

I have written the following piece of code separately inside `trunk>public>test.php` to optimize my existing Zend_Search_Lucene Index file:

```
<?php
require_once ('../library/Zend/Search/Lucene.php');

// Open existing index
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open('../application/searchindex');

// Optimize index.
$index->optimize();

echo "Index Optimized";
echo "Total documents: ".$index->numDocs();
```

And I am getting following error:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Search/Lucene/Document/Html.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\apache\htdocs\dezyre_oct\trunk\library\Zend\Search\Lucene.php on line 27

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Search/Lucene/Document/Html.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\apache\htdocs\dezyre_oct\trunk\library\Zend\Search\Lucene.php on line 27
```

Could anybody help to use Zend_Search_Lucene component separately outside Zend Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set include path of your zend library something like below

```
$path = '/var/www/lib/Zend';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

after that include Zend Loader to use zend autoloader

```
require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
```

[Basic Autoloader Usage](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.autoloading.usage.html)